# How can I give full permissions to Google Drive REST API?

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-drive-api, google-admin-sdk

I'm trying to create an app that copies and deletes existing spreadsheets. I've set up the DriveQuickstart from https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/quickstart/java

The error that I'm getting now is saying that I do not have sufficient permissions to access that, even after I click the "Allow" button that comes up on my browser after I run the sample.

My code is exactly the same as on the quickstart link.

I'm getting this stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Insufficient Permission",
    "reason" : "insufficientPermissions"
  } ],
  "message" : "Insufficient Permission"
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:145)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:321)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1056)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
    at DriveQuickstart.main(DriveQuickstart.java:110)
```

Comment: I have this problem too. I don't see where I'm supposed to add scopes.

Answer (score 5):

To build on adjuremods response, this is what worked for me:

1) Change this line:

```
private static final List<String> SCOPES =
    Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY);
```

to:

```
private static final java.util.Collection<String> SCOPES =
    DriveScopes.all();
```

2) Delete your existing stored credentials so that it will fetch them again, and reexecute your program:

```
rm ~/.credentials/drive-java-quickstart/StoredCredential
```

Note: you want an OAuth Client ID called `client_secret.json` file, not the client_id.json file (I think - that's what worked for me anyway).

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using the exact code form the QuickStart, it may have something to do with the scope set, its currently set as `DriveScopes.DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY`, which if you check out its meaning in the [Choose Auth Scopes](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/scopes) page, it states

> Allows read-only access to file metadata, but does not allow any access to read or download file content

You can look at the cited page to know what scope it is you'll exactly use. Its most likely going to be `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`, so check out the `DriveScopes` class for the constant of the same nature.